# JDBC connection takes long time and fails

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I'm debugging, the code is stuck on the connection creation and after a while an error is thrown that too much time has passed.

**connection creation:**

```
//Loading and registering Oracle database thin driver                
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//Creating a connection between Java program and Oracle database.
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servicename","username","password");
```

**Error:**

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 183633 ms.

Comment: Have you been able to connect via other tools such as SQL*Developer, or have you tried `tnsping servicename` ?  Can you `ping hostname` ?

Comment: Hi Mark, I am able to connect via SQLdevloper and able to ping hostname.

Comment: If you have access to the server, take a look at the TNS listener log, located in something like `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/tnslsnr/$HOSTNAME/listener/trace/listener.log`